# Is there a way to remove the directory the VS Code terminal?

Tags: powershell

I'm new to development and I am trying to learn how to code. I was previously following a course and using Replit, but when I decided to make the change and use a code editor (VS Code) I ran into this problem that I can't seem to solve.

The following is what gets returned in the terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Documenti\GitHub\LearningPythonExercises> & C:/Users/andre/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe c:/Users/andre/OneDrive/Documenti/GitHub/LearningPythonExercises/BasicsExercises/CommonListPattern.py
None
PS C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Documenti\GitHub\LearningPythonExercises>
```

[Image of the code and terminal response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPeiq.png)

Is there a way to remove the `PS` and directory that gets printed or to hide it so it looks less clustered?

Comment: Everything is correct. list.sort method returns None, therefore None is printed. What you want to do it to sort, and then print(all_friends) in the next line

Comment: In python the `.sort()` method returns `None`.

Comment: You're right. Thank you for the prompt responses. I thought that I had broken something...
Is there a way to hide the PS directories that get printed above the returned values so that it looks less clustered?

Comment: I've always thought the answer is "no" - vscode is printing out what it's doing, and what its doing is starting python and starting your code. You could just run your own code with `python CommonListPattern.py` or `python.exe CommonListPattern.py` or whatever it is that works for your terminal (`python3` is sometimes required). I think it's just something you'll get used to. Most serious programs are not going to limited to one-liners in the terminal, but for ad hoc stuff you just learn to ignore that startup output (note: terminal and vscode F5 sometimes handle relative paths differently!).